# Sonar on Travis: ERROR You must define the following mandatory properties for 'Unknown'

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube, travis-ci, sonar-runner

I'm trying to setup [SonarQube](http://www.sonarqube.com) on Travis for a Java project by following Travis documentation https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/sonarqube/

My resulting my `.travis.yml` file is as follows:

```
sudo: required
cache:
  directories:
    - $HOME/.m2
language: java
services:
  - docker
jdk:
  - oraclejdk8
os:
  - linux
env:
  matrix:
    - NEO_VERSION=3.0.9
      WITH_DOCKER=true
      EXTRA_PROFILES=-Pwith-neo4j-io
    - NEO_VERSION=3.1.2
      WITH_DOCKER=true
      EXTRA_PROFILES=-Pwith-neo4j-io
addons:
  sonarqube:
    organization: ${SONAR_ORGANIZATION}
    token:
      secure: ${SONAR_TOKEN}
    branches:
      - master
      - sonarqube
before_script:
script: 
  - build/run.sh
  - sonar-scanner
install: true
after_success:
  - mvn clean test jacoco:report coveralls:report
  - "[ ${TRAVIS_PULL_REQUEST} = 'false' ] && [[ ${TRAVIS_BRANCH} = 'master' ]] && mvn clean deploy -DskipTests --settings ./deploy-settings.xml"
```

My resulting `sonar-scanner.properties` file is:

```
# must be unique in a given SonarQube instance
sonar.projectKey=liquigraph
# this is the name and version displayed in the SonarQube UI. Was mandatory prior to SonarQube 6.1.
sonar.projectName=Liquigraph
sonar.projectVersion=1.0

# Set modules IDs
sonar.modules=liquigraph-cli,liquigraph-core,liquigraph-maven-plugin,liquigraph-spring-boot-starter,liquigraph-examples

# Modules inherit properties set at parent level
sonar.sources=src
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
sonar.language=java
```

But when I commit and Travis start building, sonar job fails with following logs:

```
. . .
$ sonar-scanner
INFO: Scanner configuration file: /home/travis/.sonarscanner/sonar-scanner-2.8/conf/sonar-scanner.properties
INFO: Project root configuration file: NONE
INFO: SonarQube Scanner 2.8
INFO: Java 1.8.0_111 Oracle Corporation (64-bit)
INFO: Linux 4.4.0-51-generic amd64
INFO: User cache: /home/travis/.sonar/cache
. . .
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: Total time: 13.770s
INFO: Final Memory: 64M/505M
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
ERROR: You must define the following mandatory properties for 'Unknown': sonar.projectKey, sonar.sources
ERROR: 
ERROR: Re-run SonarQube Scanner using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
```

I did put my `sonar-scanner.properties` in the root of my project folder. Why travis cannot find and instead is using `/home/travis/.sonarscanner/sonar-scanner-2.8/conf/sonar-scanner.properties`?

Comment: Why are you using the SonarQube Scanner while your project seems to be a Maven project? Why not use `mvn sonar:sonar`?

Comment: @JulienH.-SonarSourceTeam yeah I think i'll use instead the maven plugin, I first wanted to try setting up sonar as described in the doc (this is why)

Comment: @JulienH.-SonarSourceTeam any doc for configuring the maven sonar plugin with travis??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your project is a Maven project, then simply use the Scanner for Maven: `mvn sonar:sonar`

Look at https://about.sonarqube.com/get-started/ for details.

If you really want to use the SonarQube Scanner, then your issue is that you are not using the correct name for the configuration file. It should be `sonar-project.properties`.